# MapStruct - mapping nested List<String>

Tags: java, hibernate-mapping, mapstruct

How can I use MapStruct to map nested List?

Here is my entity class:

```
public class ChannelEntity {

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable
    List<String> loggedUsers = new ArrayList<>();
...

}
```

I'd like to map it to:

```
public class Channel {
    
     List<String> loggedUsers = new ArrayList<>();
...
}
```

For now my mapper looks like:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "cdi")
public interface JpaPersistenceChannelMapper {

    ChannelEntity toEntity(Channel channel);
    Channel toDomain(ChannelEntity channelEntity);
}
```

But it maps only 'normal' properties like Long, Integer etc., but it avoids nested List.

Comment: What version of Mapstruct are you using? Mapstruct and MapstructProcessor? I can´t reproduce your Problem. For me the mapping works fine for Lists of Strings as well as single properties. (Using Spring componentModel, mapping ChannelEntity to Channel ).

Comment: Yes, I have MapStruct and MapstructProcessor. Version 1.4.2.Final.

I'm not using Spring. I'm using Java EE

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem. I need to have getters and setters in both classes.